# Xcode 7: iOS some russian Localizable strings are not working

Tags: ios, xcode7.3, nslocalizedstring

I have an app with Russian translation.
It looks strange, but some strings are not displayed in Russian. For example I have two strings:

```
"Kennwort" = "Пароль";
"Benutzername" = "Имя пользователя";
```

First one doesn't work, but second one works and so on... Some values are displayed, some are just missing. What is difference? What can be a problem? I've really tried a lot. Maybe someone has any idea or had similar problem? I would be really grateful for any help or advice. thank you!

example of using:

```
passwordSection.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Kennwort", nil);
```

Comment: Try writing any other string in place of this. Just to verify. I mean
"Kennwort" = "jasdkajhs";

Comment: @AadilAli yes, I was trying. It doesn't find any value for key "Kennwort".

Comment: Can you make sure there is one key "Kennwort". because i am also having same issue so i found there was same key is used again. try searching it in whole project.

Comment: @AadilAli, there is only one value with key "Kennwort"... 
it doesn't see as well: 
"Server Adresse" = "IP-адрес";

Comment: please add code snippet where you are using it.

Comment: @AadilAli added code to the question

Comment: some things to try, paste both keys into hex edit, maybe there is an invisible char... also make sure the file is saved as utf-16 with correct BOM...

Comment: also check the file in resources of the built app, maybe it has an old version

Comment: @GradyPlayer hex strings are the same. and i saved the file as utf-16... still the same

Comment: did you check the built product (right click on it in products, reveal in finder, then right click and say "Show Package Contents" then navigate to where the strings files are (should be resources) and check to make sure the key is in there and correct.)

Comment: @GradyPlayer, the mistake was so simple... there was one ";" than needed... thank you so much for your help.